# Is it possible to upsert Prechat data in a custom Lightning Snap-in?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, liveagent, pre-chat, pre-chat-api, snap-ins

Here are some related links:

1. [Custom Pre-Chat Component Sample Using Aura](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_lightning_components_prechat_sample_aura.htm)
2. [Custom Pre-Chat Component Sample Using JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_lightning_components_prechat_sample_javascript.htm)
3. [Find and Create Records Pre-Chat API Code Sample](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_creating_records_prechat_code_sample.htm)

Based on link 3, it seems like if we were using a `Visualforce Page` for our Prechat form, we would be able to upsert a single `Contact` record, in order to associate the `LiveChatTranscript` to an existing record. However, I'm having a hard time hunting down how that would be done using a custom `Lightning Component` hooked up to a Snap-in, as described in link 1.

We're trying to do the association based on a Unique External Id field. When an existing value is populated in the Prechat form, no `Contact` record is created nor associated to the `LiveChatTranscript`. When a new value is populated, a new `Contact` is created and associated. The behavior observed so far seems to indicate any `DML` failures are silent, and the transcript record can be created regardless of any failures up to that point.

I can't find any documentation on the Prechat API surfaced via the [`lightningsnapin:prechatAPI`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightningsnapin:prechatAPI/documentation) component. It doesn't seem to have any sort of analogue to the `findOrCreate` map that would have allowed us to upsert in classic.

Is it possible to have a Lightning Prechat Snap-in upsert a `Contact` record based on a `Unique External Id` field included in the prechat form? If so, how?

Comment: I know you're trying to use the API in #3, have you considered using a server side controller for your snap-in? I don't know if they work like Lightning Components or not (from the code, it appears like they do), but that might provide a work-around.

Comment: Is there an Apex API for Prechat?

Comment: Adrian, I've never worked with the LiveAgent API. I simply saw the similarity to Lightning Components in the links you provided and that's why I made the suggestion. I do know there's also a LiveAgent REST API that might also offer some some means of providing a workaround for this issue. I'm assuming your real issue is related to the new Lightning Console and you may want to consider filing a case on this as a possible bug or parity discrepancy. Use the access you now have. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Snap-Ins for Web Developer Guide` contains this page:

## [Pre-Chat Code Examples](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.snapins_web_dev.meta/snapins_web_dev/snapins_web_prechat_code_examples.htm)

#### Find contacts but don't create new ones

In this example, we don't want to create contact records — we only want to find them. To disable creation of a record, set doCreate to false for all the required fields for the record. This code disables a common default behavior of creating a contact record with each chat session.

```
 embedded_svc.settings.extraPrechatInfo = [{
   "entityFieldMaps": [{
     "doCreate":false,
     "doFind":true,
     "fieldName":"LastName",
     "isExactMatch":true,
     "label":"Last Name"
   }, {
     "doCreate":false,
     "doFind":true,
     "fieldName":"FirstName",
     "isExactMatch":true,
     "label":"First Name"
   }, {
     "doCreate":false,
     "doFind":true,
     "fieldName":"Email",
     "isExactMatch":true,
     "label":"Email"
   }],
   "entityName":"Contact"
 }];
```

Comment: This solution is only available for the Snap-Ins using the JavaScript implementation, so this is not available if implementing a Snap-Ins prechat form in Lightning, which is limited to what you can do with the lightningsnapin:prechatAPI (which is very limited).